# Customers who shop from each product category; how many product categories did they shop on average in SQL Server project?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

This is what I did till now.I would like to find out that; customers who shop from each product category; how many product categories did they shop on average?
Can someone complete the project or give me a hint. Thanks in advance

This is what output must be looked
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGDKL.jpg)

```sql
SELECT CategoriesAndCustomers.CategoryName,
       CategoriesAndCustomers.CustomerID,
       CustomersAndTotalCategoryCount.TotalCategoryCount,
       COUNT(CustomersAndTotalCategoryCount.TotalCategoryCount)
FROM (SELECT PC.[Name] AS CategoryName,
             SOH.CustomerID
      FROM [AdventureWorks2017].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] SOH
           LEFT JOIN [AdventureWorks2017].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] SOD ON SOH.[SalesOrderID] = SOD.[SalesOrderID]
           LEFT JOIN [AdventureWorks2017].[Production].[Product] P ON SOD.ProductID = P.ProductID
           LEFT JOIN [AdventureWorks2017].[Production].[ProductSubcategory] PSC ON PSC.ProductSubcategoryID = P.ProductSubcategoryID
           LEFT JOIN [AdventureWorks2017].[Production].[ProductCategory] PC ON PC.ProductCategoryID = PSC.ProductCategoryID
--WHERE PC.[Name] = 'Accessories' --AND CustomerId = 29610
) CategoriesAndCustomers
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT SOH.CustomerID,
                       COUNT(PC.[Name]) AS TotalCategoryCount
                FROM [AdventureWorks2017].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] SOH
                     LEFT JOIN [AdventureWorks2017].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] SOD ON SOH.[SalesOrderID] = SOD.[SalesOrderID]
                     LEFT JOIN [AdventureWorks2017].[Production].[Product] P ON SOD.ProductID = P.ProductID
                     LEFT JOIN [AdventureWorks2017].[Production].[ProductSubcategory] PSC ON PSC.ProductSubcategoryID = P.ProductSubcategoryID
                     LEFT JOIN [AdventureWorks2017].[Production].[ProductCategory] PC ON PC.ProductCategoryID = PSC.ProductCategoryID
                --WHERE PC.[Name] = 'Accessories' --AND CustomerId = 29610
                GROUP BY SOH.CustomerID) CustomersAndTotalCategoryCount ON CategoriesAndCustomers.CustomerID = CustomersAndTotalCategoryCount.CustomerID
--WHERE CategoriesAndCustomers.CustomerID=11001
GROUP BY CategoriesAndCustomers.CategoryName,
         CategoriesAndCustomers.CustomerID,
         CustomersAndTotalCategoryCount.TotalCategoryCount
ORDER BY CategoriesAndCustomers.CategoryName;
```

Comment: The syntax is not correct for MySQL or Oracle, so I assume the correct tag is SQL Server.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: table aliases make the code more readable

Comment: I changed the tag through SQL Server.I hope the point is clear.I wrote these codes nicely

Comment: The OP does use aliases, @SteveC , just *very* long ones for their subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate your question with expected output? It is not clear why you are using left join in the first place and what you are really trying to count?

These would be a mess as a comment:

```
SELECT
      SOH.CustomerID
    , PSC.ProductCategoryID
    , COUNT(*)  AS CountPerCategory
FROM  [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]                   SOH
      INNER JOIN [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]        SOD ON SOH.[SalesOrderID]=SOD.[SalesOrderID]
      INNER JOIN [Production].[Product]            P ON SOD.ProductID=P.ProductID
      INNER JOIN [Production].[ProductSubcategory] PSC ON PSC.ProductSubcategoryID=P.ProductSubcategoryID
      INNER JOIN [Production].[ProductCategory]    PC ON PC.ProductCategoryID=PSC.ProductCategoryID
GROUP BY SOH.CustomerID, PSC.ProductCategoryID;

SELECT SOH.CustomerID
     , PSC.ProductCategoryID
--     , PSC.ProductSubcategoryID
     , COUNT(*) AS Counts
      FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] SOH
           inner JOIN [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] SOD ON SOH.[SalesOrderID] = SOD.[SalesOrderID]
           inner JOIN [Production].[Product] P ON SOD.ProductID = P.ProductID
           inner JOIN [Production].[ProductSubcategory] PSC ON PSC.ProductSubcategoryID = P.ProductSubcategoryID
           inner JOIN [Production].[ProductCategory] PC ON PC.ProductCategoryID = PSC.ProductCategoryID
GROUP BY SOH.CustomerID, PSC.ProductCategoryID
--, PSC.ProductSubcategoryID
WITH ROLLUP;
```

EDIT: Average:

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(tmp.CountOfCategories AS DECIMAL)) AS AverageCategories
FROM (
SELECT
      SOH.CustomerID
    , COUNT(DISTINCT PSC.ProductCategoryID)  AS CountOfCategories
FROM  [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]                   SOH
      INNER JOIN [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]        SOD ON SOH.[SalesOrderID]=SOD.[SalesOrderID]
      INNER JOIN [Production].[Product]            P ON SOD.ProductID=P.ProductID
      INNER JOIN [Production].[ProductSubcategory] PSC ON PSC.ProductSubcategoryID=P.ProductSubcategoryID
      INNER JOIN [Production].[ProductCategory]    PC ON PC.ProductCategoryID=PSC.ProductCategoryID
GROUP BY SOH.CustomerID
) tmp;
```

Comment: I editted the question that what output must be,the point why I use left join is avoiding data loss

Comment: For example,I did shopping from clothing category and added my shopping from 2 categories,you did shopping from clothing category and added your shopping from 4 categories.Now I did shopping from 3 category,you did shopping  5 category so (5+3)/2=4 is the avarage of the clothing where people did clothing and other categories

Comment: @temeribrahim, sorry I don't understand. And I don't understand why would there be any data loss if you used inner join. Wouldn't it then be a data integrity problem? Are you sure that schema requires LEFT JOIN?

Comment: you can be right but the point is not type of join.if you go to the results ,it is okay for me.Did you get the point that I explained it above

Comment: @temeribrahim, no, as I said, I don't understand what you are asking. I don't understand what do you mean by "you did shopping...". I am not sure, if you simply mean to average the result of the queries I provided returning.

Comment: I editted my question and put there a photo,it can explain it.Also the question is that I'm a person.I did shopping from 3 categories and you did shopping 5 categories.There are 2 person and 8 sales from categories.8/2 equals to 4 that means each category sales is 4.I hope it is clear

Comment: @temeribrahim, I am afraid it is not clear at all. Your sample in words would end up with a scalar average value. On the other hand, your image have some Groups who knows where they came from. I am anyway editing to add average.